# Как узнать нажата ли клавиша при создании компонента React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как узнать нажата ли клавиша при создании компонента React(в ComponentDidMount). Мне необходимо создавать компоненты по нажатию Ctrl+Enter, при этом обработчик находится в каждом компоненте. Хотелось бы увидеть, нажата ли клавиша Ctrl при создании компонента.

Comment: а можно код компонента?

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Он очень большой, больше 1к сточек в нем. Это обычный React.PureComponent, который представляет собой строку с разными формами ввода. Мне интересно как узнать зажата ли клавиша Ctrl на клавиатуре после создания( в cmponentDidMount методе)

Comment: обычного PureComponent на 1к строчек не бывает

Comment: компонент создается после нажатия комбинации?

Comment: 1615 если быть точным(но если его почистить - то 1200 будет)), а если еще и поотделять некоторые части - то можно хорошо сократить.

Comment: Да, компонент создается после нажатия этой комбинации на другом таком же компоненте(естественно при разных условиях, но это не имеет значения)

Comment: Ситуация вообще простая - я нажимаю Ctrl+Enter, когда активным является верхний компонент и по ней создается еще один компонент выше, дальше я не отпуская Ctrl  нажимаю опять Enter - должен создастся еще один компонент выше, но Ctrl был зажат на прошлом компоненте, а создание нового я смотрю на последнем активном. Таким образом Ctrl новый компонент не видит.

Comment: Просто видит нажатие Enter -  а это совсем другое действие я делаю